# Laravel stop render Livewire before length is less than 2 characters

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have an input in Laraval Livewire for searching in a model and show the results immediately.

I want 2 way data binding. so I've used `wire:model`:

```
<input type="text" wire:model="query">
```

but the problem is I want to **start sending requests after the user entered the third character**.

I know we have `wire:model.debounce.1000ms` but it's not useful for me. because it will start sending a request after 1000 millisecond that we stopped typing.

I know we have `wire:model.lazy` but it will start sending a request after we clicked another place or unfocused from the current element.

Comment: There are no more custom directives you can use in this case.. you need to add a button to submit the query and before submitting you check the length

Comment: @PsyLogic is there any way to control sending data by javascript? 
for example, add an `if()` condition...

Comment: @Raskul you can achieve this using alpins js inside livewire component.

Comment: @rehman-akbar whould you give me a clue?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

As I mentioned before it is better to use a submit button for that action
another way which I didn't tried it yet is , (try one of them)

```
class SearchPosts extends Component
{
    public $search = '';

    protected $queryString = [ 
       'search' => ['except' => fn() => count($this->search) < 3],
       //'search' => ['except' => fn($value) => count($value) < 3],
    ];

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.search-posts', [
            'posts' => Post::where('title', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')->get(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Component**

```
<div>
    <input wire:model.debounce="search" type="search" placeholder="Search posts by title...">

    <h1>Search Results:</h1>

    <ul>
        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <li>{{ $post->title }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Whould you please add the component code too?

Comment: sure, I added an example , token from the doc and